# How to check if line in text file equals to a specific string?

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract lines from a text file, and make them keys for a new dictionary. So far, I've done this:

```
file = open(FileName, 'r')
dictionary = {}
for line in file:
    if line == ("Red" or "Yellow" or "Blue"):
       dictionary[line] = '' # And then I'll edit this empty string later. 
return dictionary
file.close()
```

I feel like the "if line == ..." part isn't correct, or maybe I haven't read the file correctly? It isn't working.

Can someone point me in the right direction, without giving a straight answer?
Thank you for reading through this! I appreciate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values)

Comment: Oh yes, that is quite similar! I'll check it out, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Your feelings are correct. You see, Python's if statements do not work like an English setence. The second part of your if statement: `("Red" or "Yellow" or "Blue")`, is a *boolean expression*. The `or` operator takes two values, and returns the first value which is true. In this case, since any non-empty string in Python is considered true in boolean terms, then your boolean expression returns "Red". This means that what your if statement is really saying is:

```
if line == "Red":
```

What you need to do is test `line` against each value. While this could be done by going through each value and saying: `if line == "Red" or line == "Blue"...`, Python was a much better way. Using the `in` operator you can create an iterable with all the values you want to test `line` against. Python will then test if `line` is equal to any value in the iterable. In your case, using a tuple will be fine, but if you need to test `line` against many more values, you should use a `set()` instead:

```
if line in ("Red", "Yellow", "Blue"):
    # do stuff
```

One last point is that `line` could contain a newline. You can remove the newline by using `.strip()`. So your finally solution would be:

```
if line.strip('\n') in ("Red", "Yellow", "Blue"):
        # do stuff
```

Comment: :O Ahh that makes sense. I see where I went wrong. I'll work on it! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
if line in ("Red", "Yellow", "Blue"):
```

To check that your line does not contain spaces or `\n`, you can use:

`line.strip('\n ')` instead of just `line`:

```
if line.strip('\n ') in ("Red", "Yellow", "Blue"):
    dictionary[line.strip('\n ')] = ''
```

Comment: Also make sure to check for the trailing newline char.

Comment: Consider new line and using a set instead of a tuple (Python 2.7)
`line.strip() in {"Red", "Yellow", "Blue"}`

Comment: @js837 Why a set? Tuples which only contain a few items are cheap to make.

Comment: `strip('\n')` may not always work - Windows platforms add a `'\r'` as well. Since the target strings do not have spaces, `line.strip()` might work best

Comment: "Why a set?" <- because sets have O(1) lookup time